# Pinescript entry and close executing with 1 bar delay

Tags: pine-script, trading

I've been trying to create a strategy that creates a label and enters a trade if:

1. The bar is the second consecutive green bar to open above 9 day MA line.
2. If it's under the oversold value.

And Exit the trade if the opposite to the above is true.

I don't understand because the label AND strategy functions are acting on the same line of logic, so why is the strategy opening 1 bar after my entry label?

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Swing Strat", pyramiding=1, overlay=true, initial_capital=100, currency=currency.GBP)


//Plotting SMA lines
MAPeriod9 = input(9, title="9 MA Period")
MA9 = sma(close, MAPeriod9)
MAPeriod180 = input(180, title="180 MA Period")
MA180 = sma(close, MAPeriod180)

plot(MA9, color=color.blue, linewidth=1)
plot(MA180, color=color.red, linewidth=1)

// Creating the RSI
rsiSource = input(title="RSI Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
rsiLength = input(title="RSI Length", type=input.integer, defval=14)

rsiOverbought = input(title="RSI Overbought Level", type=input.integer, defval=70)
rsiOversold = input(title="RSI Oversold Level", type=input.integer, defval=30)

//get rsi value
rsiValue = rsi(rsiSource, rsiLength)
isOverbought = rsiValue >= rsiOverbought
isOversold = rsiValue <= rsiOversold

//identifying green confirmation bar
MAcrossover = crossover(close, MA9)
barsCrossO = barssince(MAcrossover)
greenbc = barsCrossO==1 and MA9<open and open<close and open[1]<close[1]

//assigning the entrypoint variables
entrypointsignal1 = (isOversold)
entrypointsignal2 = (greenbc)

//combining the entrypoint signals into the final entry point
entrypoint = (entrypointsignal1 and entrypointsignal2)


//CREATING THE EXIT POINT

//creating the red bar confirmation
MAcrossunder = crossunder(close, MA9)
barsCrossU = barssince(MAcrossunder)
redbc = barsCrossU==1 and MA9>open and open>close and open[1]>close[1]

//assigning the exitpoint variables
exitpointsignal1 = (isOverbought)
exitpointsignal2 = (redbc)

//combining the exitpoint signals into the final exit point
exitpoint = (exitpointsignal1 and exitpointsignal2)

//plotting the entry point to the chart
plotshape(entrypoint, title="Entry Point", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.cross, text="Entry Point")
plotshape(exitpoint, title="Exit Point", location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.cross, text="Exit Point")

//creating the positions
if (entrypoint)
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true)
    
if (exitpoint)
    strategy.close(id="EL")
```

Comment: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#why-are-my-orders-executed-on-the-bar-following-my-triggers

Answer (score 0):

Try using process_orders_on_close=true in the first line of the strategy function. You can take reference of this link Help needed with strategy - Entry is off by 2 candles. Even if problem not resolved then the possible solution is to make the exact same strategy in study.